# Mocking a celery task call

Tags: python, django, celery, pytest

I have a celery task that needs to be mocked. It is being called as:-

```
def trigger_task(id):
    task_name(id).delay()
```

I tried using this but because I am passing a parameter it is not getting mocked properly.

```
@patch('domain.tasks.tasks.task_name.delay')
def test_abc:
    pass
```

How can i Mock it?

Comment: The way you're passing a parameter is wrong - you need to pass any arguments to the task to `delay()` instead, i.e., `task_name.delay(id)`. Then your mock will work as expected.

Comment: yeah that was the issue. thanks